# Unexpected generated explicit App IDs

Tags: ios, xcode, app-store-connect

Can we still use wildcard App IDs on Connect?

I have just added an app on iTunes Connect by clicking + and New iOS App. It has generated explicit IDs for all my apps.

For Bundle ID I chose "Xcode iOS Wildcard App ID - *" and typed a Bundle ID Suffix like "com.testapps.test". I filled in the rest of the form and created the app.

In member centre under App IDs, I can see an App ID with name "com-testapps-test" and ID "com.testapps.test", with Game Center and In-App-Purchase enabled. I didn't create this. I don't remember this happening last time I created and app on Connect. In fact there are now explicit App IDs for all apps I have created previously, which didn't exist before. Furthermore when I refreshed my account in Xcode Preferences, it has created and downloaded Development Profiles for all these IDs.

When I go back to Connect to look at the new App and choose About This App under More. It has Bundle ID "com-testapps-test - com.testapps.test" rather than the wildcard and suffix. If I try to change it to use the wildcard ID, I get "Your app information could not be saved. Try again. If the problem persists, contact us.".

Comment: Did you solve this issue?

Comment: Not really. AFAICR I basically ignored this, used the * ID to build and it worked. Now that you mention it, that reminds me Apple never answered the question I sent them.

Comment: Were you using phonegap? Interested if you've encountered another issue, do you recall getting an error - ''ERROR ITMS-90034 - Missing or invalid signature "

Comment: No, not phonegap. Connect / member centre just generated a whole load of IDs I didn't need or ask for. This was my first iOS app. In the development stage I did get in a mess with certificates and IDs with xcode telling me things were missing and solved that by deleting everything and starting from scratch. But beware... Connect wouldn't let me reuse an app ID after deleting everything even though nothing had been submitted or published for that app.